# How the checkpoints behave in SSIS ?

Tags: ssis

How the checkpoints behave in SSIS ? Whether it commits the data in db at each checkpoint ? or it just store it in XML file only and start the next run with the xml file only ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question. What is the exact issue you are facing with Checkpoints. Have you looked at the MSDN site for information on checkpoints. If not, read this - [MSDN Checkpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140226.aspx)

Checkpoints are essentially used for restartability of the package in case of failure. Checkpoint information is stored in an XML file. But no data is stored. It is committed as per the package transaction configuration.

Comment: Have you read the artcile yet? It has answers to the questions you have asked.

Comment: You as the package developer need to know at which steps in your package it can be restarted and set up checkpoints that way. It's just a shorthand way to help tell an operator that a package can be started in the middle without data being inconsistent. Seriously. Read the article.